# What would be the good name for this operation?

Tags: scala

I see that Scala standard library misses the method to get ranges of objects in the collection, that satisfy the predicate:

```
def <???>(p: A => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
  val buf = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[List[A]]()
  var elems = this.dropWhile(e => !p(e))
  while (elems.nonEmpty) {
    buf += elems.takeWhile(p)
    elems = elems.dropWhile(e => !p(e))
  }
  buf.toList
}
```

What would be the good name for such method? And is my implementation good enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go for **chunkWith** or **chunkBy**

As for your implementation, I think this cries out for recursion! See if you can fill out this

```
@tailrec def chunkBy[A](l: List[A], acc: List[List[A]] = Nil)(p: A => Boolean): List[List[A]] = l match {
  case Nil => acc
  case l    =>
    val next = l dropWhile !p
    val (chunk, rest) = next span p
    chunkBy(rest, chunk :: acc)(p)
}
```

**Why recursion**? It's much easier to understand the algorithm and more likely to be bug-free (given the absence of vars).

The syntax !p for the negation of a predicate is achieved via an implicit conversion

```
implicit def PredicateW[A](p: A => Boolean) = new {
  def unary_! : A => Boolean = a => !p(a)
}
```

I generally keep this around as it's astoundingly useful

Comment: Excellent implementation! One note - I believe you forgot to add `reverse` in the Nil case.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def chunkBy[K](f: A => K): Map[K, List[List[A]]] = ...
```

Similar to `groupBy` but keeps contiguous chunks as chunks.
Using this, you can do `xs.chunkBy(p)(true)` to get what you want.

Comment: I like this one too, and I'll add it alongside with `chunkWith` (chunkWith is similar in function to dropWhile/takeWhile, so it should sound like them, and `chunkBy` is more similar to `groupBy`). But I think that in my concrete case avoiding Map would be a bit better for performance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to call it `splitWith` because `split` is the string operation that more-or-less does that, and it's similar to `splitAt`.

Incidentally, here's a very compact implementation (though it does a lot of unnecessary work, so it's not a good implementation for speed; yours is fine for that):

```
def splitWith[A](xs: List[A])(p: A => Boolean) = {
  (xs zip xs.scanLeft(1){ (i,x) => if (p(x) == ((i&1)==1)) i+1 else i }.tail).
  filter(_._2 % 2 == 0).groupBy(_._2).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2.map(_._1))
}
```

Comment: I tend to declare functions fst and snd, eg "def fst[A, B](ab: (A, B)) = ab._1". This way, code like "x groupBy (_._1)" becomes "x groupBy fst". Makes for more readable code; I hate _1 and _2!

Answer (score 1):

Just a little refinement of **oxbow**'s code, this way the signature is lighter

```
def chunkBy[A](xs: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): List[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def recurse(todo: List[A], acc: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = todo match {
    case Nil => acc
    case _ =>
      val next = todo dropWhile (!p(_))
      val (chunk, rest) = next span p
      recurse(rest, acc ::: List(chunk))
  }
  recurse(xs, Nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, obviously I'd have my chunkBy as an inner def